# Generating Unique random numbers effectively in Java

Tags: java, random

I want to generate unique random numbers from range `0 to 999,999`.

In order to achieve that, I tried:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) { 
            list.add(new Integer(i)); // Add numbers from 0 - 999,999 into ArrayList
        }

        Collections.shuffle(list); // shuffle them

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i)); // printed unique numbers
        }
```

The problem is the larger the number I want to generate, the longer the time it takes, for the above method, it took about `700ms`.

But if I use `Random()` to generate them without filter duplicate numbers, it only takes `2ms`

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
  int digit = 0 + new Random().nextInt((999999 - 0) + 1); 
  System.out.println(digit);
}
```

Is there other way to generate unique random numbers in a more efficient manner?

Comment: Not sure how much this will gain you, but you should create your list with the capacity you need, i.e., `new ArrayList<Integer>(1000000)`.  Reallocations are expensive.

Comment: You can try to initial the list to the size you need. This will help not to resize during add.

Comment: Unfortunately, the longer (either in time or quantity) that you want each new random number to be unique over, the longer it will take to generate it using traditional random methods.
Why do you need both unique and random?  Or perhaps I should ask, are you sure you mean Random as a cryptographer would define it?
Perhaps something like a random UUID would solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a set of random integers like this:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
Random rand = new Random();

while (set.size() < 10) {
    set.add(rand.nextInt((1000000)));
}
```

The idea is that the set data structure will remove duplicates.

Comment: so if existing numbers found in the set will the set replace the duplicate one or add a new entry?

Comment: Why the strange - 0 + 1 business? The compiler will replace it with a constant, of course, but it doesn't seem to make anything clearer

Comment: @cwfei Neither.  It simply won't add it.

Comment: One problem with this is that you lose the order of whatever Random produced and you're relying on the unspecified order HashSet. A way to fix this is to add new items to an ArrayList and only use the set for dupe checking.

Comment: @pvg, in what case would the order be useful?

Comment: @JustinD. in the case where you want the random data to be actually random. HashSet doesn't have any sort of contract about what order it will return items to you. For all you know, it will return them in sorted order. Or even numbers first.

Comment: @pvg is right. For example, with the current implementation of `HashSet`, if you use this method to add 10 random numbers in the range 0 to 10 and print it, it will always say (`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`).

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to create a list of 1000000 numbers and shuffle them all if you only need 10. There is also no need to write `new Integer(i)` (you can just use `i`).

In Java 8 there is a very short way to do this:

```
int[] arr = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, 1000000).distinct().limit(10).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

If you are using Java 7 or below, you could do this:

```
Random rand = new Random(); // Only do this in Java 6 or below. Now you should use ThreadLocalRandom.current().
int[] arr = new int[10];
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int index = 0, a; index < 10;)
    if (set.add(a = rand.nextInt(1000000)))
        arr[index++] = a;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: I tried your java 8 approach, it was slower than Justin's solution, but way less code though

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer by virtue of being correct alone but the braceless, side-effect-cramming, for-loop-abusing style needlessly trades clarity for brevity.

Comment: @pvg Braces are overrated. :) I've never heard a convincing reason why a `for` or an `if` needs a brace if what follows is really short. I'll admit, declaring `a` and `index` together, and assigning `a` in the `if` is pretty ugly.

Comment: @PaulBoddington The whining about it is generally about the fact that it's easy to make a mistake if you add or move code around later. The OS X 'goto fail' bug is arguably one nasty and catastrophic (and maybe even convincing!) example.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code

its work perfect

```
private int count;

private boolean in = true;

public static final Random gen = new Random();

int[] result;

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public void addUse() {

    result = new int[getCount() + 10];

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        String setup = ("" + i + i + i + i + i);

        result[getCount() + i] = Integer.valueOf(setup);

    }

}

public boolean chechArray(int number) {

    for (int i = 0; i < getCount() + 10; i++) {

        if (result[i] == number) {

            in = true;

            break;

        } else {

            in = false;

        }

    }
    return in;

}

public void printRandomNumbers() {

    Random gen = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {

        int get = gen.nextInt(100000 - 10000) + 10000;

        if (chechArray(get) == false) {

            result[i] = get;

        } else {

            i--;

        }

    }

}

public void viewArray() {

    printRandomNumbers();

    for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {

        System.out.println((i + 1) + " Number is = " + result[i]);

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    RandomDemo3 rd2 = new RandomDemo3();
    rd2.setCount(20);
    rd2.addUse();
    rd2.viewArray();

}
```